# Auto-partitioning/batching large Spring Data JPA in-clauses

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

A common pattern is causing problems when the input lists grow large. Many Spring Data interfaces that extend `org.springframework.data.jpa.repositoryJpaRepository` declare queries that use an in-clause.  A simplified example:

```
@Query("SELECT c.someImportantData FROM SomeComponent c WHERE c.someForeignKeyId IN (:someIds)")
List<Object> getImportantDataBySomeIds(@Param("someIds") Collection<UUID> someIds);
```

This works great as long as the list of `someIds` is small.  With `Postgresql` small is defined as 32767.  However, several internal uses exceed this number and that causes errors/exceptions.  Currently, those are fixed by partitioning the main list and then passing in smaller collections via the calling software.  While this approach also works, I am wondering if there is a way within JPA/SpringDataJPA to accomplish the same?  I am using Spring Data JPA 1.11.12 if that matters.